# queryCache.find() is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I am having a problem with **react query**. When I delete an item from my list with mutation, I need to refresh the page to see the change.
And when I try queryCache.find('key') I get undefined.
Also I dont have a method queryCache.refetchQueries() (saw that on a tutorial but it seems its depr. )

Here is my code:

```
const { data, status, error, refetch } = useQuery('posts', fetchPosts);

 const queryCache = new QueryCache();
 const query = queryCache.find('posts');

 console.log(query); // undefined
```

Here is a mutation:

```
 const mutation = useMutation(deletePost, {
        onSuccess:  () => {
            // can I here somehow do a refetch?
        }
    });

    const deleteOne = async (id: string) => {
      mutation.mutate(id)
    }
```

Why am I getting undefined and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of react-query are you working with? In v3, which is the latest major version, you will need to work with `queryClient` instead of `queryCache`:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient()
const posts = queryClient.getQueryData('posts')
```

for refetches after mutation, it's generally best to use:

```
queryClient.invaliateQueries("posts")
```

This is also how it's shown in the docs: [invalidations-from-mutations](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/invalidations-from-mutations)